# Updating dictionary key/value pairs as dataframe changes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to update a dictionary to account for changes that may occur in a dataframe.

Say I have the followng df:

```
color    name
 red      Jim
```

I want to update a dict kinda like so:

```
dict = dict.update({df['color'] : df['name'})
```

which would give me `dict = {'red' : 'Jim'}`

After another iteration, the df might look like

```
color    name
 green    Pam
```

And after updating the dict again would leave me with:

`dict = {'red' : 'Jim', 'green' : 'Pam'}`

Comment: Legends has it, never name your dictionary, `dict`.

Comment: @harvpan how about `dict1`? ;P

Comment: ^ yes much better, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can zip the two columns of interest, then call `dict.update`:

```
mydict.update(zip(df['color'], df['name']))
```

Or,

```
# update works with Series too
mydict.update(df.set_index('color')['name'])
```

---

**Minimal Code Sample**

```
df
  color name
0   red  Jim   

df2
   color name
0  green  Pam

d = {}
```

```
d.update(zip(df['color'], df['name']))
d.update(df2.set_index('color')['name'])

d
# {'green': 'Pam', 'red': 'Jim'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do for loop here

```
for _, y  in df.iterrows():
    d[y['color']]=y['name']
```